# Calling setState in useEffect causes white screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
export const useStage = (player, resetPlayer) => {
  const [stage, setStage] = useState(createStage());

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateStage = (prevStage) => {
      ...
      return newStage;
    };
     setStage((prev) => updateStage(prev));
  }, [player.collided, player.pos.x, player.pos.y, player.tetromino]);

return [stage, setStage];
};
```

I'm attempting to build tetris within React but I've come across an error which I haven't been able to solve for days. For some reason when I call setStage within useEffect, it causes a white screen, when I comment out the single line it goes back to normal.

In case it helps, I'm following along with a video: https://youtu.be/ZGOaCxX8HIU?t=5101

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: probably because of the dependency array. change it from [player.collided, player.pos.x, player.pos.y, player.tetromino] to [player]

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on either [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)? I think there must be some logical error (like Null/undefined pointer exception, etc) in the `updateStage` function. Also, did you check the browser console? You will see some helpful logs there.

Comment: Check your browser's dev console for errors